# Access html table stored in session

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I wanted to get the best approach for what Im trying to do. I have a sproc in the database that does import from another database to ours and links information. If linked information is missing it generates errors ro be resolved by the user. In my codebehind, I am getting these errors, I create a html table adding rows for each error. Now I want to persist this information across multiple pages so I am storing this in session, since its just an html table and not a heavy duty control like a grid, whats the best way
to store the HTML table in session or any other way and how can I access this in Javascript or Jquery on the client side so I can utilize Jquery functions to show an expandable div displaying this information

```
protected void BtnAddDock1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlGenericControl RadDocksDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("RadDocksDiv");
            RadDocksDiv.Style["display"] = "block";

            Session["Docking"] = "Open";

            Table tblErrors = new Table();
            tblErrors.ID = "tblErrors";
            tblErrors.CssClass = "tabularData";
            tblErrors.Width = 800;
            TableHeaderRow hr = new TableHeaderRow();
            // hr.ID = "tblErrorsHeaderRow";
            TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
            //thc.ID = "tblErrorsHeaderCell";
            thc.Text = "Error Descriptions";
            hr.Cells.Add(thc);
            tblErrors.Rows.Add(hr);
            Panel pnlErrors = (Panel)Master.FindControl("pnlErrors");

            Table dobleTable = (Table)Master.FindControl("tblErrors");

            if (dobleTable == null)
            {
                pnlErrors.Controls.Add(tblErrors);



                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                    string error = "This is a website generated Import Error that needs to be added to the panel on Masterpage!";
                    TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
                    tableCell.Text = error;
                    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
                    tblErrors.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                }


                Session["ErrorsTable"] = tblErrors;
            }
            //Table tblErrors = (Table)Master.FindControl("tblErrors");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and here is how I am trying to get this in Javascript but all I can see is just System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table when I try to get it from session.

```
    //Access html table in  session
    var dockingState = '<%= Session["Docking"] %>'

    if (dockingState == "Open") {

        // This doesnt return the html table correctly?!?
        var sessiontblErrors = '<%= Session["ErrorsTable"] %>'

        if (sessiontblErrors != null) {
            var pnlErrors = $("[id$=pnlErrors]");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to keep errors in session to show across pages, I would do it in this way. Instead of creating HTML table and storing in session, i would create a list of Errors in Session and access it whenever  i need and display it in whatever format i want. It can be a HTML table, Ordered List , Spans etc...

I would simply create a class to hold my Error Messages

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
  public string ErrorCode { set;get;}
  public string Message { set;get;}
}
```

and in your code, instead of creating the HTML table row, i will add this to a list

```
List<ErrorMessage> objErrorList=new List<ErrorMessage>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  ErrorMessage objError=new ErrorMessage();
  objError.ErrorCode=5020;
  objError.Message="There is such a bad error!";
  objErrorList.Add(objError);
}
if(objErrorList.Count>0)
{
  Session["Errors"]=objErrorList;
}
```

And Whenever i want this i will return this from Session. I would wrap this in a function.

```
public List<ErrorMessage> GetErrors()
{
  List<ErrorMessage> objList=new List<ErrorMessage>();
  if(Session["Errors"]!=null)
  {
    objList=(List<ErrorMessage>)Session["Errors"];
  }
  return objList;
}
```

If you want this from javascript, you can get it by making a call to a server page (an aspx page / ashx handler) using jQuery ajax/getJson. Some thing like this.

```
var strErrors="<ul>";
$.getJSON('geterrors.ashx', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      strErrors+="<li>" + val + "</li>";
    });
});
strErrors+="</ul>";

$("#yourMsgDiv").html(strErrors);
```

Where in `geterrors.ashx`, you will call our GetErrors method and convert that toJSon  format and return.

**The main advantage in this approach is that the Presentation is not tightly tied to data**. We can show the error message in various styles.

Comment: Hi Shyju Thanks for your good suggestion, I am trying this out, havnt worked with ashx handlers have tried Json with a webservice call but I am not getting any data back in Javascript here is what I have in Services.asmx

Comment: @Shokwave: I encourage you to post another question for that with relevant details. So people will help you.

Comment: @Shokwave : Use firebug/ fiddler to see what calls are being made and what response is coming back.

Comment: Hi Shyju Thanks for your good suggestion, I am trying this out, havnt worked with ashx handlers have tried Json with a webservice call, do I have access to the Sessionstate objects in a Webservice page or is that why you were suggesting an ashx handler?

Comment: ashx does not have all page events compared to an aspx page. so i prefer ashx.

Comment: ok btw I found out you do have access to the session state you just have to enable it on the web method like                  [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]

Answer (score 1):

> I create a html table adding rows for each error

Actually this line `Table tblErrors = new Table();`  creates a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) which is an ASP.NET server side control.

If you really want to create an HTML Table you'd need to use the [`Render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.render.aspx) method to generate the HTML. That said I think you should do as [Shyju](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336976/119477) recommends and remove the presentation from the Data.

Answer (score 0):

Read following links and you will have idea what to use. Session is a costly operation in terms of memory point of view and if you have large volume website that would be a big problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/freelance91/ASPNETstatemanagementtechniques01012007212655PM/ASPNETstatemanagementtechniques.aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article61.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31994/Beginners-Introduction-to-State-Management-Techniq

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a major misunderstanding here.

`Session` stores serialized string representations of *objects*.

```
Session["ErrorsTable"] = tblErrors;
```

It is very important that you understand that `tblErrors` in your c# code *does not equal*:

```
<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

`tblErrors` is an object, and it has a class, just like any other c# class. (paraphrasing) When the page is rendered by asp.net to send to the client, that class is *translated* as html. However, if you put an instance of the class into `Session`, that is not what you will get. You are storing the actual object, which `Session` serializes and deserializes for you.

I hope this helps, I realize this is a difficult topic to explain.